# Is there a way to play the Headshot sound in CSGO competetive?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I want to hear the play'headshot' sound from Unreal Touranemnt ( or whatever file I give ) in CS:GO competetive mode when the console says something like this:

> you killed 'x' with a headshot...

or

> 'x' killed you with a headshot...

I know you cant mess with the game files i.e: you cant mod a skin because the game will kick you. I just want to play a soundfile when a headshot occours by me or on me. Is there a way doing this from the console or a .cfg file?

Comment: While this could be done as a server-side mod, I don't think it can be done on the client-side.

Comment: you can mod skins but they will only show up for you. everyone else will see them as default skins

Answer (score 1):

Powerlord is correct here. Unless you host your own server which specifically plays the "Headshot" sound from UTournament, you won't be able to play a soundfile when you kill someone with a headshot.

The closest thing could be having, say HLDJ, have 1 clip with the headshot sound, and bind it to a key that would play that sound to all your teammates (or globally if alltalk is on).

Comment: However I am aware of that you cant alter the main server to play files from your pc so I just want to do this on my side just for me. Is this change anything?